# How do I call late bound assembly.[name].method from VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm looking at late binding functionality from Crystal Reports in VB.NET and one statement has me a bit stumped....

```
dim oObject as CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExcelDataOnlyFormatOptions = CrystalDecisions.[Shared].ExportOptions.CreateDataOnlyExcelFormatOptions()
```

I am now no longer referencing the "CrystalDecisions.Shared" DLL, so how do I call this functionality "late bound"?

Getting ahold of the Assembly itself is easy enough using

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile
```

And any of the other objects I need I can easily create using the **.CreateInstance** method on the assembly, but I'm not sure how to translate that specific statement, and in particular the **[Shared]** part of it into a "late bound" syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.... I found the answer which was actually a lot more straightforward than I expected it to be:

```
        Dim oExcelOptsDataOnlyMethod As Reflection.MethodInfo
        oExcelOptsDataOnlyMethod = CRSharedAssembly.GetType("CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions").GetMethod("CreateDataOnlyExcelFormatOptions", Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
        oObject = oExcelOptsDataOnlyMethod.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```